# ASP.NET mvc 4 controller parameter always null when sending json to controller, why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, object, controller

There are some similar posts already here, and tried every solution suggested, and still does not work... I can not get value inside controller, it is always null. Below is the code. Am I missing something?

**Client side javascript**

```
   function getChart() {
       JSONString3 = { HAxis : [{ Name : "monday" }] };
       jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("getChart","SBM")",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'json',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: JSONString3,
            success: function (data) {
                var imagestring = btoa(data);
                $('#ChartImage').attr('src', "data:image/png;base64," + imagestring + "?" + new       Date().getTime());
            }
        })
        jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = false;
    }
```

**MVC Controller**

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult getChart(YAxis HAxis)
    {
        YAxis XAxisvalue = HAxis;
        Charts chart = new Charts();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        chart.Chart.SaveImage(ms);
        string image = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.GetBuffer());
        return File(ms.GetBuffer(), "image/png", "Chart.png");
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class YAxis
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried posting as plain text params instead of an HAxis object?

Comment: Tried that also, did not work also. I suspect it has something to do with the object name on the server side. Testing it right now...

Comment: No not working. The only thing working for now was controller in this form: "public ActionResult getChart(string XAxis)" and data to post in this form "data: {"XAxis" : "testValue" }"

Comment: I'd scrape everything in the controller and just try and pass a string value. Drop your break point and see if the value is still null. If so, you likely got issues on the JS side.

Comment: Ok, I managed to get string... But deserialization into object still does not work. Do I have to configure something in the Web.config file to work properly?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Thank you guys for the directions and solutions. The solution is a combination of all of your suggestions, so I decided to round it up in one post.

Solution to the problem is as follows:

1. `contentType` should be `application/json` (as Ant P suggested above)
2. json data should be in form of `JSONString3 = {"Name" : "monday" }` (as Ant P suggested above)
3. before sending to controller, json should be `stringifyed` as follows: `JSONString3 = JSON.stringify(JSONString3)` (as Quan suggested)

**Client side javascript**

```
function getChart() {
               JSONString3 = { "Name" : "monday" };
               jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("getChart","SBM")",
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: JSON.stringify(JSONString3),
                    success: function (data) {
                        var imagestring = btoa(data);
                        $('#ChartImage').attr('src', "data:image/png;base64," + imagestring + "?" + new       Date().getTime());
                    }
                })
                jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = false;
    }
```

**MVC Controller**

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult getChart(YAxis HAxis)
{
    YAxis XAxisvalue = HAxis;
    Charts chart = new Charts();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    chart.Chart.SaveImage(ms);
    string image = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.GetBuffer());
    return File(ms.GetBuffer(), "image/png", "Chart.png");
}
```

**Model**

```
public class YAxis
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Instead of this:

```
JSONString3 = { "Name" : "monday" };
```

we can do this:

```
var JSONString3 = {};
JSONString.Name = "monday";
```

But we still need to stringify object before posting to controller!!!

> ***To pass multiple objects to controller, below is the example***

**Client side javascript**

```
   function getChart() {

        //first json object
        //note: each object Property name must be the same as it is in the Models classes on    server side
        Category = {};
        Category.Name = "Category1";
        Category.Values = [];
        Category.Values[0] = "CategoryValue1";
        Category.Values[1] = "CategoryValue2";

        //second json object
        XAxis = {};
        XAxis.Name = "XAxis1";
        XAxis.Values = [];
        XAxis.Values[0] = "XAxisValue1";
        XAxis.Values[1] = "XAxisValue2";

        //third json object
        YAxis = {};
        YAxis.Name = "YAxis1";

        //convert all three objects to string
        //note: each object name should be the same as the controller parameter is!!
        var StringToPost = JSON.stringify({CategoryObject : Category, XAxisObject : XAxis, YAxisObject : YAxis});

        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("getChart","SBM")",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'html',
            data: StringToPost,
            success: function (data) {
                var imagestring = btoa(data);
                $('#ChartImage').html(data);
            }
        })
    }
```

**MVC Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult getChart(Category CategoryObject, XAxis XAxisObject, YAxis YAxisObject)
{
    //do some stuff with objects here and return something to client
    return PartialView("_Chart");
}
```

**Category model**

```
public class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }
}
```

**XAxis model**

```
public class XAxis
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }
}
```

**YAxis model**

```
public class YAxis
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Hope it will help someone to clarify the whole picture!

Comment: This answer was extremely helpful to me.  Thank you.

Comment: For future readers: The behavior is very different (on the MVC side) between POST requests and GET requests. Mine failed (null parameter) until I switched to using POST.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem (parameter always null), but my solution was different.

Make sure that your ActionResult method parameter doesn't have the same name as the JSON object property.

In this example I renamed myParam to myNewParam to differentiate from MyParam property.

Example:
This won't work:

```
    var myObj = {
        ID: '0',
        MyParam: $('#mycontrol').val(),
    }; 

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyModel")',
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(myObj),
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
        }
    })

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MyAction(Class1 myParam)
```

This will work:

```
    var myObj = {
        ID: '0',
        MyParam: $('#mycontrol').val(),
    }; 

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyModel")',
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(myObj),
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
        }
    })

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MyAction(Class1 myNewParam) -->renamed
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you're trying to pass an array of objects:

```
JSONString3 = { HAxis : [{ Name : "monday" }] };
```

When your action only wants one:

```
public ActionResult getChart(YAxis HAxis)
```

Maybe you only meant to pass one?

```
JSONString3 = { "Name": "monday" };
```

Comment: Try `JSONString3 = { "Name" : "monday" };` also try changing your `ContentType` to `application/json`.

Comment: server error 500 if I change `ContentType` to `application/json`

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONString3 = { "Name": "monday" };
```

You should post it to controller as a string, so use JSON.stringify to convert, i dont know how to use your ajax type, i just know to use $.post... T_T

```
 $.post('@Url.Action("getChart","SBM")', {yourJson : data:JSON.stringify(JSONString3)} , function(data) {
            if (data.success) {
var imagestring = btoa(data.name);
                $('#ChartImage').attr('src', "data:image/png;base64," + imagestring + "?" + new       Date().getTime());
   }
});
```

In controller,

```
    public ActionResult getChart(string yourJson)
        {
         YAxis  yAxis= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YAxis>(yourValue);
          //  ....... your code here
          return Json(new{success=true,name=yAxis.Name},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

** Note : JsonConvert is method of using Newtonsoft.Json; , please add Newtonsoft reference.

Answer (score -1):

Adding a datatype attribute to the controller method solved it for me.

```
[JsonFilter(Param="yourParamName", JsonDataType=typeof(YourParamType))]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult yourFunction(YourParamType YourParamName)
{
    //do some stuff
}
```

Comment: JsonFilter isn't a valid attribute.