# Login to asp mvc app from ionic app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ionic-framework

Folks, I have an ionic mobile app and mvc app. How can I send post requests with built model(data) to asp mvc controller, example is logging in.

I know that better would be using web api. But still, any ideas?

Comment: This question is way too broad to be answerable.   Also, WebAPI is part of MVC, it's not it's own standalone framework, there is nothing wrong with having WebAPI in an MVC application.  You don't have to write a completely new app to use it's features.

Comment: The main difference is that MVC controllers return **HTML**, where WebAPI controllers return **Data**.   Without using WebAPI controllers, your interactions with your backend will be very difficult from any angular/ionic based application, since every request to the server will be returning a new HTML Page, with a brand new app, instead of the Single Page Application that angular is designed to be.

Comment: Got it, but I can return json data for example, not only HTML. Another idea - are there any ways to build my model on angular side and send it with $http.post.

Comment: Here's a definitive answer on [how to POST json model to an MVC 4 controller](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20395082/3585500).