# .NET MVC post deserialize empty json object to null

Tags: angularjs, json, model-view-controller

I'm using angular resource to post json object to my MVC Controller:

```
$resource('myUrl').save(subject)
```

where subject is:

```
subject: {
  name: 'test'
  person: {}
}
```

my c# classes:

```
public class Subject
{
  public string name {get;set;}
  public Person person {get;set;}
}
public class Person
{
  public string id {get;set;}
}
```

MVC Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual JsonResult Validate(Subject subject)
{
    ....
}
```

After post subject.person = null and I expect it to be new Person()? And if I post:

```
subject: {
  name: 'test'
  person: {
     example: '123'
  }
}
```

then subject.person is not null. How can I configure my MVC app to deserialize empty json object {} not to null but to new object?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/20384242

Comment: Not at all. His JSON object was wrong and in my case subject is not null. Just person is null which is inner object

Comment: Try to write custom ModelBinder that will `new()` properties marked with some attribute say `EmptyToNewObjectAttribute`. If you don't want to create ModelBinder try to post some dummy property of person say: `{ id: 0}`