# Ajax POST array in JSON to API in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, model-view-controller

I want to send an array in a JSON string to an API and then handle the data. Despite creating a class and trying to let it map it I get it as `null`

This is my AJAX call (part of):

```
var ids = {
  rateplanIds: ['100', '200', '300']
};
$.ajax({
  url: g_appVirtualPath + "ApiFile.mvc/CheckMBB/",
  async: false,
  global: false,
  type: "POST",
  data: {
  ids: JSON.stringify(ids)
  }
})
```

This is my API (part of):

```
        public class RateplanIds
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string[] rateplanIds { get; set; }


        }


        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post), Authorize]
        public JsonResult CheckMBB(RateplanIds ids) //ids = null
        {

        }
```

Comment: add `contentType:"application/json"` for your ajax request

Comment: @vikscool I have added `dataType: "json"` following the patern in other AJAX calls in the same project.

Comment: Then @FotisPapadamis try changing your `data` to what @Narendran has mentioned.

Comment: @vikscool after changing `data` `ids` is still `null` but it is associated with the class. Previously it was just `null`

Comment: why not `string[]` as a parameter in the controller

Comment: @FotisPapadamis have you tried sending the data without `stringifying` it? as `data:{ids:{
  rateplanIds: ['100', '200', '300']
}}`.

Comment: @vikscool it needs to be sent as a JSON

Comment: @FotisPapadamis ok, then coming back to `contentType` try adding it to what I have mentioned before. As for why? `contentType` is used to specify what type of data are you sending and whereas the `dataType` is used to specify the type of data to be received.

Comment: @vikscool still `null`

Comment: Did u try using `[FromBody]` attribute for your parameter in the action method?

Comment: @akg179 yes, no luck.

Comment: @FotisPapadamis check  out [ASP.NET mvc 4 controller parameter always null when sending json to controller, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20384242/asp-net-mvc-4-controller-parameter-always-null-when-sending-json-to-controller) the answers in there solves the same issue.

Comment: @vikscool I worked it around but I will take a look at your suggested post for future issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post), Authorize]
    public JsonResult CheckMBB([FromBody]RateplanIds ids) //ids = null
    {

    }
```

instead of:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post), Authorize]
    public JsonResult CheckMBB(RateplanIds ids) //ids = null
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have to many shells around your data. The data property of the AJAX request just has to be `data: JSON.stringify(ids)`

**Note** that every `{}` is a new `Object`